# troubleshoot a timeout happening while deploying via VS

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, error, troubleshooting

Hi I am getting timeout error while trying to deploy my sp solution via visual studio 2010. It happens when my a particular feature is trying to activat. The generic error message I get goes something like this:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': A timeout has
>   occurred while invoking commands in SharePoint host process.

I've tried increasing the timeout in the IIS console for the SharePoint website (via the Advanced settings Dialog).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If I don't have that folders.. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools Should I create it?

Answer (score 3):

There is a registry value that doesn't exist by default, that can be added to change the timeout of the server, I think on development machines the default SP settings dont allow for deployment of large .WSP solutions, or could also be slower platforms.

Goto the following regustry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools

Add the following as a DWORD (wont be there by default)

**ChannelOperationTimeout**

REG_DWORD that specifies the time, in seconds, that Visual Studio waits for a SharePoint command to execute. If the command does not execute in time, a SharePointConnectionException is thrown.
**The default is 120 seconds.**

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee471440.aspx) explains at the bottom some registry keys that can be added for debugging, which includes the one mentioned.

Comment: i am using server 2016 and sharepoint 2016,i cant find that registry key

Answer (score 2):

it could be related to ChannelOperationTimeout

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee471440(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, don't forget to restart Visual Studio