# Deploying add-in to SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I am trying to deploy an add in to SharePoint Server but keep getting this error:

> "A timeout has occured while invoking commands in Sharepoint host
>   procecss"

Note: I am using vs2017 and window server 2016

I have tried to add DWORD registry key but i can't find the path below as mentioned in some post: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i found out where to really add that registry key. Note in my case SharePointTools registry didn't exist. I have created the latter manually.

This kind of key should be the same for any user. So it is stored in HKLM, not in HKCU. So the key is stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools.

Note the added Wow6432Node.

Add the following as a DWORD (won't be there by default)

ChannelOperationTimeout

Set its value to something more than 120(which is the default value). In my case 360 did the work

Answer (score 0):

There is a registry value that doesn't exist by default, that can be added to change the timeout of the server, I think on development machines the default SP settings dont allow for deployment of large .WSP solutions, or could also be slower platforms.

Goto the following regustry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools

Add the following as a DWORD (wont be there by default)

ChannelOperationTimeout

REG_DWORD that specifies the time, in seconds, that Visual Studio waits for a SharePoint command to execute. If the command does not execute in time, a SharePointConnectionException is thrown. The default is 120 seconds.

This explains at the bottom some registry keys that can be added for debugging, which includes the one mentioned.

Reference [troubleshoot a timeout happening while deploying via VS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55375/troubleshoot-a-timeout-happening-while-deploying-via-vs)

Comment: there is no sharepoint tool folder in visualStudio

Comment: i can't find that registry key